# converting extracted list items into a list in python

Tags: python, list

```
import numpy
x = [*range(1, 101)]
for n in x:
    if numpy.mod(n, 2) == 0:
        print(f'Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: {n}')
```

This code returns

```
Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: 2
Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: 4
Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: 6
```

and so on. But I want it to return the even numbers in a list form

```
Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ..., 100]
```

I tried using list(n) but it shows that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 3, in <module>
print('Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: ', list(n))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Please suggest an alternative method to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will first declare an empty list, append items to it and at last show the list:

```
en = []
import numpy as np
x = [*range(1, 101)]
for n in x:
    if np.mod(n, 2) == 0:
        en.append(n)

print(f'Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: {en}')
```

Is the long version of:

```
print(f'Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: {[x for x in list(range(1,101)) if x % 2 == 0]}')
```

Actually numpy is usless, python just has modulus operator `%`

Answer (score 0):

You should append `n` to a list.
Check it out : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Try,

```
import numpy
x = [*range(1, 101)]
output = list()
for n in x:
    if numpy.mod(n, 2) == 0:
        output.append(n)

print(f'Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: {output}')
```

Also you don't have to store the range in a variable `x`. Try using list comprehension as below

```
import numpy
output = [n for n in range(1,101) if numpy.mod(n, 2) == 0]

print(f'Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: {output}')
```

Comment: When I put print(f'Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: {output}') just under output.append(n), something odd happens that you'll have to run. Why does that happen even though there isn't a loop?(Everything works fine when the print(...) is placed as you wrote.

Comment: You have to append all the even numbers to list before printing it. If you print after each append, it'll print `[2], [2,4], [2,4,6] ` etc

Answer (score 0):

Or as a list comprehension using the `%` operator:

```
output = [x for x in range(1, 101) if x % 2 == 0]
print(f'Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: {output}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append the even numbers to a list inside your `for` loop doing. This can be done using `list.append()`:

```
even_numbers = []
for n in x:
   if numpy.mod(n, 2) == 0:
       even_numbers.append(n)
print(f'Even numbers between 0 and 101 are: {even_numbers}')
```